# Override css selector of all classes (* selector)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My website (http://www.isaacadni.com) is partly based on bootstrap. Bootstrap includes the following css code:

```
* {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box
}
```

However, I want all the elements inside a certain div with the class `youmax` to be styled with `content-box` like so:

```
.youmax {
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box !important;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box !important;
    box-sizing: content-box !important;
}
```

However, this does not seem to override the Bootstrap css. The only thing that seems to override it is using the `*` selector again, but this styles the whole page with `box-sizing: border-box;`.

How do I style the div with `box-sizing: content-box;` but have the rest of the webpage styled with `box-sizing: border-box;`

Comment: `.youmax, .youmax * { box-sizing: content-box; }` and make sure it comes after the bootstrap styles

Comment: @Issac Adni have you use your css file after bootstrap ? Use your custom css after bootstrap css.

Comment: It's probably helpful to learn a little about [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.youmax,
.youmax *,
.youmax *:before,
.youmax *:after {
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

The `!important` is not needed.

**Edited**: removed the 2 vendor prefixed rules `-webkit-` and `-moz-`. No longer needed since 2012.

Comment: I actually landed up removing the `border-box` styling from the bootstrap css, and then applying it to the part of the page that was made up from bootstrap because the `youmax` div had some `content-box` and some `border-box` in it. Many thanks!